# How to add data with Custom ID to firestore?

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

```
db.collection("users")
                .add(user)
                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentReference>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(DocumentReference documentReference) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "DocumentSnapshot added with ID: " + documentReference.getId());
                    }
                })
                .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        Log.w(TAG, "Error adding document", e);
                    }
                });
```

-Above code generates ID automatically.

How to add data with Custom ID to firestore ?
My purpose is to create a custom ID and write text data into this collection.
Can,you help me ?
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As explained in the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#set_a_document), you should use the [`set()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/DocumentReference#public-taskvoid-set-object-data) method of the [`DocumentReference`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/DocumentReference) Class.

```
db.collection("users")
        .document("theIDYouWant")  // <== Specify the Doc ID here
        .set(user)
        .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                Log.d(TAG, "DocumentSnapshot successfully written!");
            }
        })
        .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                Log.w(TAG, "Error writing document", e);
            }
        });
```